# Python: Converting multiple columns to a single column with categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

If I have this table:

| City | State | Person 1 | Person 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Atlanta | GA | Bob | Fred |

But, I want to convert it to:

| City | State | Person# | Person Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Atlanta | GA | 1 | Bob |
| Atlanta | GA | 2 | Fred |

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Hello, do you want to split by person *?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `melt`:

```
out = df.melt(['City', 'State'], var_name='Person#', value_name='Person Name')
out['Person#'] = out['Person#'].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

```
>>> out
       City State Person# Person Name
0  Atlanta    GA        1        Bob 
1  Atlanta    GA        2        Fred
```

Comment: Perfect!   Thanks for your help.